# Reducing block generation time

Tags: block-interval

Is there any drawback to reducing the time it takes to generate POW, essentially reducing block generation time and confirming transactions faster.

What if the difficulty is reduced so that the POW can be generated/mined in within a minute - in tens of seconds. 

What will be the potential issues if this is done, can this be done safely?

Comment: Thanks, this was helpful.
I am looking for more information and details on how it impacts security. Is there any detailed information available?